# Boost Serialization input stream error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I am trying to serialize a member of a derived class.  This member is inherited from a base class.  The serialization code is included non-intrusively as part of the base class header file.  The save(), load() methods are part of the base class implementation.  I getting the following error when trying to run my code:

`boost::archive::archive_exception' what():  input stream error`

Here is the relevant part of the code:

**ModelLibrary.h** (This s the Base Class)

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/set.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <fstream>

class ModelLibrary() 
{
    typedef std::pair<const ORROctree::Node::Data*, const ORROctree::Node::Data*>  Dipole;
    struct Base {
        Dipole seg1;
        Dipole seg2;
    };
    typedef std::list<Base> bases_list;
    typedef std::map <string, bases_list> SerializeHashTableCell;
    typedef NDIMVoxelStructure<SerializeHashTableCell> SerializeHashTable;

public:
    bool
    saveHashTable();

    bool
    loadHashTable();

    virtual bool
    generateHashTableArchiveName (string &filename) = 0;

public:
    SerializeHashTable shash_table_;  /***** MEMBER TO BE SERIALIZED ******/

};

// SERIALIZATION METHODS FOR THE TYPES USED TO FORM THE SERIALIZEHASHTABLE
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ModelLibrary::SerializeHashTable & h, const unsigned int version)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < h.total_num_of_voxels_; ++i)
    ar & h.voxels_[i];
  ar & h.num_of_voxels_;
  ar & h.total_num_of_voxels_i_;
  ar & h.bounds_;
  ar & h.spacing_;
  ar & h.min_center_;
}


template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ModelLibrary::Base & b, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & b.seg1;
  ar & b.seg2;
}


template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ORROctree::Node n, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & n.data_;
  ar & n.center_;
  ar & n.bounds_;
  ar & n.radius_;
  ar & n.parent_;
  ar & n.children_;
}

template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ORROctree::Node::Data d, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & d.id_x_;
  ar & d.id_y_;
  ar & d.id_z_;
  ar & d.neighbors_;
  ar & d.lin_id_;
  ar & d.num_points_;
  ar & d.p_;

}`
} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

**ModelLibrary.cpp**

```
bool
ModelLibrary::saveHashTable ()
{
  string filename;
  generateHashTableArchiveName (filename);
  cout << "archive filename" << filename;
  std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str());
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
  // write class instance to archive
  oa << shash_table_;
  // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
  return true;
}


bool
ModelLibrary::loadHashTable ()
{
  string filename;
  generateHashTableArchiveName (filename);
  std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
  boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
  ia >> shash_table_;
  return true;
}
```

**ModelLibraryG4PCS.h**

```
class ModelLibraryG4PCS: public ModelLibrary
{
virtual bool
generateHashTableArchiveName (string &filename);

}
```

**ModelLibrary4GPCS.cpp**

```
bool
ModelLibraryG4PCS::generateHashTableArchiveName (string &filename)
{
  filename = "";
  //Concatenate all Added Models into filename
  std::map<std::string, Model*>::const_iterator model_itr = models_.begin();
  for (; model_itr != models_.end(); ++model_itr)
  {
    filename += model_itr->first;
  }

  // No Models Have been added
  if (filename == "")
    return false;

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << pair_width_ << "_" << dipole_width_ << "_" << voxel_size_ << ".hash";
  filename += ss.str();
  return true;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main() 
{
    ModelLibraryG4PCS d;
    if (!d.loadHashTable()) {
        /* Some Code to Construct a new Hash Table */
        d.saveHashTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you **NEVER** post mutilated code again for a question. I just spent 45 minutes figuring out that you randomly mutated `ModelLibrary` into `base` and `ModelLibraryG4PCS` into `Derived`. That's just not funny and completely unnecessary (it wastes all of our time). That said, make it selfcontained next time: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38cfb33d5bf388a6. It can be a **lot** shorter too.

Comment: sorry i fixed the issue with derived and base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code isn't self-contained so I can only glance over it.

For now:

```
for(int i = 0; i < h.total_num_of_voxels_; ++i)
    ar & h.voxels_[i];
ar & h.num_of_voxels_;
ar & h.total_num_of_voxels_i_;
```

How would you think this could work? Clearly, `h.total_num_of_voxels` is either zero or indeterminate at the time of the loop when deserializing. Assuming it is an array (or at least contiguously stored elements in memory), use the array adaptor:

```
ar & boost::serialization::make_array(h.voxels_, h.total_num_of_voxels_); 
ar & h.num_of_voxels_;
```

Here's a reverse engineered example making some guesses based on your original code: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d8e4aaa048381b5)**

Output

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Os -pedantic main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_serialization && ./a.out && tail *.hash
archive filenameonetwo42_4242_999.hash
22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I have asked another question with self-contained code which shows the definition of the octree Node class.  The serialization code you have here doesn't work in that case.  The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175180/boost-serialization-segfault