# Boost Serialization Segfault

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I am trying to serialize a class member.  The following snippet of code will show the relevant class definitions and the non-intrusive serialization code I have included.  I am getting a segfault during my saveHashTable() method which tries to serialize the class member shash_table_.  Here is a self-contained trimmed version of the code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/set.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct ORROctree
    {
      public:
        struct Node
        {
          public:
            struct Data
            {               
              public:
                float n_[3], p_[3];
                int id_x_, id_y_, id_z_, lin_id_, num_points_;
                std::set<Node*> neighbors_;
                void *user_data_;
            };

          public: 
            Node::Data *data_;
            float center_[3], bounds_[6], radius_;
            Node *parent_, *children_;
        };        
      protected:
        float voxel_size_, bounds_[6];
        int tree_levels_;
        Node* root_;
        std::vector<Node*> full_leaves_;                  
    };

struct ModelLibrary
{  

    template <typename T, typename REAL = float>    
    struct NDIMVoxelStructure 
    {
        T *voxels_;        
        std::vector<int> total_num_of_voxels_i_;
        std::vector<int> num_of_voxels_;
        long total_num_of_voxels_;
        std::vector<REAL> bounds_;
        std::vector<REAL> spacing_; 
        std::vector<REAL> min_center_;
};


    typedef std::pair<const ORROctree::Node::Data*, const ORROctree::Node::Data*>  Dipole;
    struct Base {
         Dipole seg1;
         Dipole seg2;
    };
    typedef std::list<Base> bases_list;
    typedef std::map <string, bases_list> SerializeHashTableCell;
    // MEMBER TO BE SERIALIZED
    typedef NDIMVoxelStructure<SerializeHashTableCell> SerializeHashTable;

  public:
    SerializeHashTable shash_table_;

  public:
    bool saveHashTable();

    bool loadHashTable();
};



// SERIALIZATION METHODS FOR THE TYPES USED TO FORM THE SERIALIZEHASHTABLE


namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ModelLibrary::SerializeHashTable & h, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & h.total_num_of_voxels_;
  ar & boost::serialization::make_array(h.voxels_, h.total_num_of_voxels_);
  ar & h.num_of_voxels_;
  ar & h.total_num_of_voxels_i_;
  ar & h.bounds_;
  ar & h.spacing_;
  ar & h.min_center_;
}


template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ModelLibrary::Base & b, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & b.seg1;
  ar & b.seg2;
}


template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ORROctree::Node n, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & n.data_;
  ar & n.center_;
  ar & n.bounds_;
  ar & n.radius_;
  ar & n.parent_;
  ar & n.children_;
}

template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ORROctree::Node::Data d, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & d.id_x_;
  ar & d.id_y_;
  ar & d.id_z_;
  ar & d.neighbors_;
  ar & d.lin_id_;
  ar & d.num_points_;
  ar & d.p_;
}
}
}

bool ModelLibrary::saveHashTable ()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << shash_table_;
    return true;
}


bool
ModelLibrary::loadHashTable ()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> shash_table_;
    return true;
}


int main() 
{
    ModelLibrary m;
    m.saveHashTable();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to initialize the data in your data structures. All primitive types that haven't been explicitely initialized will have *indeterminate* ("random") values. This includes the pointers, which means you're invoking **[Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** by dereferencing pointers to random memory locations.

Here's an update with the simplest initialization that could possibly work, and it runs clean under Valgrind. That's a good tool. Use it!

Also, crank up the compiler messages (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` at a minimum for gcc/clang).

Added in various places:

```
Data() : id_x_(0), id_y_(0), id_z_(0), lin_id_(0), num_points_(0), user_data_(0)
{
    std::fill(n_, n_+3, 0);
    std::fill(p_, p_+3, 0);
}
Node() : data_(0), radius_(0), parent_(0), children_(0) 
{
    std::fill(center_, center_+3, 0);
    std::fill(bounds_, bounds_+6, 0);
}
ORROctree() : voxel_size_(0), tree_levels_(0), root_(0)
{
    std::fill(bounds_, bounds_+6, 0);
}
NDIMVoxelStructure() : voxels_(0), total_num_of_voxels_(0) 
{ }
Base() : seg1(0, 0), seg2(0, 0) 
{ }
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e8dbe0048285c01)**

**Update** From the comment: the following lines were clearly in error:

```
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ORROctree::Node n, const unsigned int version)
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ORROctree::Node::Data d, const unsigned int version)
```

And should have read

```
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ORROctree::Node& n, const unsigned int version)
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ORROctree::Node::Data& d, const unsigned int version)
```

Comment: This solution works great but I am getting a different problem with my real code has classes intead of struct but has the same heirarchy and data members.  For some reason the dtor of Octree::Node is being called from the serialization function which takes Octree::Node as the template argument and its causing the segfault on the statement delete[] children_ (part of the dtor).  I am not sure if this is something you can help me with without seeing the code but I don't understand why would the serliazer ever call the dtor of Octree::Node.  Also stacktrace for the segfault shows 600+ calls

Comment: When I run it with valgrind it doesn't crash but it shows an invalid read by size 8 problem, details here:  here:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1suzW2E0VYodqzXZxCakx3RPPcN88xLlB6cEIa2SLbpw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Any insights would be appreciated.  Been struggling with this for hours.

Comment: I can't tell any of this, since you're not showing any of the relevant code (in the code you gave, there isn't a single destructor, nor delete). Anyways, `ORROctree::Node::~Node` is, obviously, invoked because you pass it by value in the `serialize` function, which is clearly an error (besides that, it will be very good to check your Rule Of Three on all the types; again, you're not showing all the code so I can't help you). I've fixed the code with the two `&`s that were missing: **[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e8dbe0048285c01)**

Comment: On a tangent, I'd appreciate if you could make follow-on questions new questions.